# react-native restrict numbers and special character TextInput

Tags: react-native

I am new to react-native and I am trying to restrict numbers and special character and user should able to type alphabets only.

I am trying this by the following code but it's not working.

```js
<TextInput style={styles.inputUserName}
    underlineColorAndroid='#053075'
    placeholder="Enter Name"
    autoFocus={true}
    placeholderTextColor="#053075"
    value={this.state.userName}
    onChangeText={(userName) => this.onChangeName(userName)}
    onEndEditing={(e: any) => {
        if (!this.state.nameRegex.test(this.state.userName)) {
            this.setState({ autofocusMob: true });
            alert("Invalid Username")
        }
    }}
/>

onChangeName(userName) {
    this.setState({ userName: userName });
    let len = this.state.userName.length;
    if (!this.state.nameRegex.test(userName)) {
        if (this.state.userName === "") {
            this.setState({ userName: "" });
        }
        else {
            var str = this.state.userName.substring(0, len);
            this.setState({ userName: str });
            alert("Only alphabets are allowed");
        }
    }
}
```

above code not working perfectly, it restricts special character and numbers but not able to erase first character and length is still increase if I press backspace...
does anyone know how can I solve this issue?

Comment: did you want to check one by one of the text or you wanna check after the user finish typing?

Comment: I want to check one by one..